# Exclude Woocommerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a beginner as far as Woocommerce is concerned.

I wanted to apply a series of sale prices to certain product categories and show the new prices below each product image in a display on home page.

I found a code snippet online and it works fine BUT it displays the new sale prices to EVERY category and product. However, I want to exclude one product category.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
// first remove the filter to run new price filter.
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 
'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 ); 

// rewrite woocommerce_get_price_html callback.
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $instance ) { 
    echo "Single: $110 + GST<br>King Single: $120 + GST<br>Double: $130 + 
GST";  

    return $price; 

    //echo " After Price Text. ";
}; 

// add the filter  again to override previous one
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 
'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

My question is - how do I extend this code to stop these new prices being applied to every product category. In other words, how do I exclude a particular product category?

I've tried wrapping the code above in the following 'functions (?) but with no success:

```
if(!is_product_category( 'christmas')){ }

if($category->name !== 'Christmas'){ }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: is_product_category is not appropriate inside 'woocommerce_get_price_html' hook.... instead  use $instance variable where u will get product details and fetch category from that.

Comment: @Alice I'm a Woocommerce newbie. What, exactly do you mean by "use $instance variable"?